# На странице 2 серые области

Tags: html, bootstrap

На странице:

http://ec2-34-212-140-26.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/admin/category/edit?id=7&

есть 2 серые области вверху страницы под заголовком "Category Update" и внизу вокруг 3-х кнопок обновления.

Не нашел откуда они и как их убрать?

Comment: Наугад: margin collapse.

Answer (score 2):

***Для того что ниже Category Update:***
В файле style.css

```
.bg-title {
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 15px 15px 10px;
    margin-bottom: 25px; //измени на 0px
    margin-left: -25.5px;
    margin-right: -25.5px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
```

***Для того что около кнопок обновления:***
В файле app.scss

```
#page-wrapper {
    padding: 0 0 60px; // тут измени на  'padding: 0 0;'
    min-height: 9px;
    background: #edf1f5;
}
```